# Can there be duplicately named tokens?

Tags: token

I just want to clarify about this statement 'An asset is uniquely identified by an asset ID, which is a pair of both the policy ID and asset name.'

I'm guessing there can be duplicately named tokens where the asset name is the same, as long as the policy ID is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A token is uniquely identified as `ploicyId` + `tokenName`

the policy id is the hash of the rules imposed on minting and burning of the token.

the token name is the arbitrary name of the token ( there could be multiple tokens with the same rules ).

so it can very well happen that there are two tokens with the same name but different rules for minting/burning.

### A token is NOT uniquely identified by the asset fingerprint

this is explained in the [CIP itself](https://github.com/cardano-foundation/CIPs/tree/master/CIP-0014#design-choices)

TLDR: even if *extremly unlikely*, it is possible for two different tokens to have the same asset fingerprint. The scope of the fingerprint is to have a quick way to distinguish between tokens but the final check should always be `policyId` + `tokenName`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be more than one token with the same name, but there cannot be more than one token with the same token fingerprint. Pretty sure the fingerprint is just the bech32 encoding of `(name, tokenId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is technically possible. If you do this you will end up with a fungible token (FT) as opposed to a non-fungible token (NFT).

As the most obvious example, all the Lovelace (Ada) in your wallet have the same policy id and token name.

The uniqueness of a token name within a policy id is the responsibility of whoever controls the minting process.